# Show archives as a drop-down in the main navigation menu

Tags: archives, navigation, dropdown

I am using the [Independent Publisher: 2 theme](https://wordpress.com/theme/independent-publisher-2/markrai.blog). It looks [like this](https://raamdev.com/) in action. I would like to be able to access my blog archives by clicking on the navigation menu, as a drop-down.

In other words, I don't want the Archives to simply be a link that goes to another page. I want it to be a drop-down which shows archives by month.
Is this possible?

Comment: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-post-type-archive-in-wordpress-navigation-menus/

Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: No, that is taking the user to an archives page. It's basically a link. What I am trying to do is have the archive navigation link expand into a drop-down, once pressed. It will show Dec 2017, Jan 2018, Feb 2018 etc.